# Add button column in a databound datagridview

Tags: winforms, forms, datagridview

i have a datagridview. i bound it to a list. now i want to show a column at the end of it. but that column apprear in wrong possition.

this is my code

```
    grdPatientAppointment.DataSource = lst;


        grdPatientAppointment.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
        //grdPatientAppointment.Columns["AdmitDate"].Visible = false;
        //grdPatientAppointment.Columns["DischargeDate"].Visible = false;
        grdPatientAppointment.Columns["AppointmentID"].Visible = false;

        grdPatientAppointment.Columns["PatientrName"].DisplayIndex = 0;
        grdPatientAppointment.Columns["Age"].DisplayIndex = 1;
        grdPatientAppointment.Columns["Address"].DisplayIndex = 2;
        grdPatientAppointment.Columns["ContactNo"].DisplayIndex = 3;
        grdPatientAppointment.Columns["Dieseas"].DisplayIndex = 4;
        grdPatientAppointment.Columns["AppointmentDate"].DisplayIndex = 5;

        DataGridViewButtonColumn btnColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        btnColumn.HeaderText = "Treat";
        btnColumn.Text = "Treat";
        btnColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;            
        grdPatientAppointment.Columns.Insert(6,btnColumn);
```

here is output:

[image: here is output]

but i want that button to the end of datagrid view

Answer (score 4):

Add column instead of inserting it to the GridView. It will automaticallyy append it to the end of column collection.

```
    grdPatientAppointment.Columns.Add(btnColumn);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [DisplayIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx) property to change the order of the columns:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkfe535h.aspx

Comment: Yes i did it but still not solved the problem.
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

just add code below

```
grdPatientAppointment.Columns.Insert(I, btnColumn)
```

I is index of column you want to add

Answer (score 0):

Use `grdPatientAppointment.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`

Then add all columns your grid will receive from DataSource and bind them from editor.