# What is the best way to add action to datagrid column button?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi there i have a windows form application and i have a datagrid with last column beign a button column. I have read that to be able to answer to the click event i have to use "cellClick" event handler but when i use this the event triggers no matter is the button clicked or is the cell clicked in the corner. So is there a better way to this and how. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: are you using DataGridView and DataGridViewButtonColumn like in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085930/add-button-column-in-a-databound-datagridview

Comment: Yes i`m using dataGridView and DataGridViewButtonColumn .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using datagrid view then this the solution

This is the DataGridView handler you need to capture the button click event.

```
this.dgvList.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(DGV_CellContentClick);
```

This is the button click handler example

```
public void DGV_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int selectedRowIndex = int.Parse(e.RowIndex.ToString());

    if (this.dgvList.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == buttonColumn && selectedRowIndex >= 0)
    {
        //do what ever you want
       // DataRow dr = DataGridViewHelper.GetDataRow(this.dgvList);
        //MessageBox.Show((string)dr["FirstName"]);
    }
}
```

i hope it will helps you....