# Adding a button to a Winforms DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to add a control (e.g. a button) to a Winforms DataGridView cell in C#?

(What I'm aiming at is putting various kinds of controls in different cells of the grid...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085930/add-button-column-in-a-databound-datagridview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do like this....

There're two ways to do this:

- 1). Cast a DataGridViewCell to a certain cell type that exists. For
  example, convert a DataGridViewTextBoxCell to
  DataGridViewComboBoxCell type.
- 2). Create a control and add it into the controls collection of
  DataGridView, set its location and size to fit the cell that to be
  host.

See my sample code below which illustrates the tricks.

Code Snippet

```
    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("name");
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add("");
        }
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;

        /*
         * First method : Convert to an existed cell type such ComboBox cell,etc
         */

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa","bbb","ccc" });
        this.dataGridView1[0, 0] = ComboBoxCell;
        this.dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "bbb";

        DataGridViewTextBoxCell TextBoxCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        this.dataGridView1[0, 1] = TextBoxCell;
        this.dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = "some text";

        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell CheckBoxCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
        CheckBoxCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.dataGridView1[0, 2] = CheckBoxCell;
        this.dataGridView1[0, 2].Value = true;

        /*
         * Second method : Add control to the host in the cell
         */
        DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
        dtp.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
        //add DateTimePicker into the control collection of the DataGridView
        this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(dtp);
        //set its location and size to fit the cell
        dtp.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 3,true).Location;
        dtp.Size = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 3,true).Size;
    }
```

Comment: Whilst the second method does display the control, it stays static when the the cells are scrolled - is there any way to lock the new control to the underlying cell?

Comment: The first method worked well, the second causes the control to "fall out" of the grid when scrolled. I guess you could use the format event to move it back again.

Answer (score 6):

The `DataGridViewButtonColumn` is a provided column type that contains a clickable button.  You can add your own controls to the cells:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx

Bear in mind it isn't always trivial, but I have seen someone put an entire `DataGridView` into a cell - looked weird.

There are also other provided columns:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
DataGridViewImageColumn
DataGridViewLinkColumn
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

You can change these in the column editor in the designer in Visual Studio, or add them in code to the Columns collection.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that I can add ANY kind of control into a DataGridViewButtonColumn? When I stumbled upon this I thought it was a column full of buttons ;-)

Comment: @Boris No not to the Button column, you can create a column type that hosts any control and add that column type to the grid.  For example you might make a DataGridViewNumericUpDownColumn that hosts a NumericUpDown control.  The column is coded to host a particular control type, it's not a runtime decision.

Comment: But I think there is still a misunderstanding: With this approach, does the whole column get the same type of control? Because what I'd like to have is a different kind of control in every cell.

Comment: Yes in this approach the whole column gets it, because usually the entire column contains the same data type in the grid.  I've not seen, nor do I know of, a solution that allows individual cells to contain different editing controls.

Comment: @Boris Actually you could define a DataGridViewPanelColumn that has the ability to add and remove child controls to the panel depending on what you need.  Not necessarily the cleanest or easiest way to achieve it though.

Answer (score -3):

I would add it in the designer and make a template field.  Easy way to go and put anything you want in the datagridview

Example

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="somedatagrid" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="somebutton" runat="server" Text="some button" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the question was about winforms, not .NET webpages.