# usercontrol with datagrid winforms c#

Tags: winforms, datagridview, user-controls

am new to winforms and I want to create a user control with datagrid ? I have to use that usercontrol in other winforms...please  how can I achieve this ??..

Answer (score 0):

1.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920555/display-user-control-in-datagridviewcell
2.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916919/adding-a-button-to-a-winforms-datagridview
3.http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

Many links will available in Google ............

Comment: @anand.. thanks for your response.. unfortunately none of your links have how to create datagridview user control in winforms...I am looking for datagridview as usercontrol.. yeah I googled it but could not find one...:(

Comment: you will get information regarding Creating user control by Datagridview in GOOGLE. But what are the new functionalities can added to your user control you have to decide. 
I think you are not searched properly please go with [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)

Comment: I created the usercontrol with datagrid in it using the msdn documentation.. Thanks..!!

Comment: @msbyuva, is this answer is useful to you?