# Adding controls to Listbox

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I know I can use `listBox.Controls.Add(new Button());` but I need to add several controls as rows, preferably from a List and set it as datasource. I have tried the following with no success:

```
var list = new List<Control>();

list.Add(new Button());
list.Add(new Button());
list.Add(new Button());

listBox1.DataSource = list;
```

Answer (score 4):

I have decided to use a [flowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) instead. This seems like the best option right now.

Answer (score 1):

A ListBox is not designed to be a container control. Its scrollbar cannot scroll the controls. It is in general something you want to avoid, putting a lot of controls in, say, a Panel whose AutoScroll property is True will make your UI unresponsive. Controls are expensive objects.

Comment: what about DataGridView?

Comment: I found something on DataGridViews which is what you would want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916919/adding-a-button-to-a-winforms-datagridview

But to be honest; WPF is 10x more flexible to this type of program you want to write. Highly recommended

Comment: You could try to add the controls dynamically to the listbox; that will work for sure: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5625f956-c5c8-487a-a12d-608d7294e05a/how-to-add-controls-to-listview-control?forum=winforms

Comment: yes but it only adds it to the first "row", not all the rows.

Answer (score -2):

I would advise you to use StackPanel instead of Listbox
you can read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx)
also, you must add Button object in you list and in StackPanel like this:

```
Button b = new Button();
list.Add(b);
stackPanel.Children.Add(b);
```

so you can work with you buttons in stack panel via list

Comment: sorry, I didn't know that question about winforms:(